# Why does the electrical conductivity increase as the temperature decreases?

Tags: physical-chemistry, concentration, electrolysis, conductivity

I am measuring the dependence of electrical conductivity of ( NaCl and $\ce{CH3COONa}$ solutions  with concentration 9g/L) with temperature using conductivity meter.

Theoretically the conductivity should decrease as the tempreture decrease, but unfortunately that does not seem to happen. 
As you can see, as I start measuring conductivity at  $\pu{85 ^\circ C}$ it decreases with decrease in temperature till $\pu{65 ^\circ C}$ ( the first three data) then again start to increase.
I repeated the experiment again and again but am getting the same result .
The conductivity start to increase around $\pu{65 ^\circ C}$! Why is this happening?

[image: in the picture the x axis is Temperature in c and in y axis the conductivity]

Comment: I edited your question, just check that I made no error. Also what does this statement *"....conductivity decreases with decrease in temperature **the first three date**"* mean?

Comment: Oh sorry i mean data ( in the table)

Comment: I write the question at the end of the work so i can see know a lot of mistakes 

Comment: The problem just that in my expermint the conductivity increase at the Temperature decrese after reaching 65 c

Comment: Did you verify/repeat the calibration of instruments used and double check the condition of any standard solutions used?

Comment: These are small changes... does it matter that density will decrease at higher temperatures? Also, is the electrode spacing constant as temperature changes?

Comment: I use KCl as standard solution i will try to calibrate the instrument one more time